# I can't get the fetched data to render on to the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to render the fetched data on my page but I can only see the data through console.log and keep getting this error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
// import StudentContainer from './containers/StudentContainer';

const API = 'https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students';


  class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            allStudents: []
         }
        }

     componentDidMount() {
         fetch(API)
         .then(resp => resp.json())
         .then(students => {
            console.log(students.students[0].city)
            this.setState({
                allStudents: students.students
            })
      });
     }
     // <StudentContainer allStudents={allStudents} />

     render () {
         console.log("state:",this.state)
         const { allStudents} = this.state
         return (
          <div className="App">
          {console.log("students:", allStudents[0])}
          <h2>Students: {allStudents[0]} </h2>
          </div>
         )
    }
 }
 export default App;
```

this console.logs an object with key values in it
 `{console.log("students:", allStudents[0])}`

but right on the bottom when I try to render it on the page,
 `<h2>Students: {allStudents[0].city} </h2>`

it becomes undefined.

Here's a snippet of the data:

````
{city: 'Fushë-Muhurr', company: 'Yadel', email: 'iorton0@imdb.com', firstName: 'Ingaberg', grades: Array(8), …}
city: "Fushë-Muhurr"
company: "Yadel"
email: "iorton0@imdb.com"
firstName: "Ingaberg"
grades: (8) ['78', '100', '92', '86', '89', '88', '91', '87']
id: "1"
lastName: "Orton"
pic: "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/voluptasdictablanditiis.jpg"
skill: "Oracle"```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
{allStudents.map((item, i) => (
                    <div key={i} className="App">
                        <h2>Students: {item.city} </h2>
                    </div>
                ))}
```

Try this , i tested it for you and it works .

Comment: you saved my day by this answer, it works from my side too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is you CANNOT display raw object onto the UI/HTML. Either create actual component/HTML using the object's data, or just `JSON.stringify` them.

In your App, try changing the line with the `<h2>` tag into: `<h2>Students: {JSON.stringify(allStudents[0])} </h2>`

---

<s>Another problem is in this line of your `StudentContainer` component `<> {"studentcontainer:", props.allStudents.map(student => student.city)}</>`.</s>

A string, then a comma, then an array is not really valid JS. Try changing this to `<pre>{JSON.stringify(props.allStudents.map(student => student.city))}</pre<` and it should display at least.

(This portion is strikethroughed because OP removed the code on the `StudentContainer` component to simplify his question, which is great)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. In that line, I was trying to see if it renders on the page. The same error remains after the edit.

Comment: I can't even get the data itself to render on the App.js file...

Comment: The rule is you CANNOT display raw object onto the UI/HTML. Either creating actual Component/HTML using the object's data, or just `JSON.stringify` them to turn it into a displayable string. Check my edit

Comment: it's a JSX isn't it? I'm used to displaying HTMLs in the render section.. what am I missing here

Comment: Yes it is JSX. JSX injects value onto HTML, and the final result should be HTML so that React and the browser can understand and display. However, you cannot throw an OBJECT into JSX brackets because React and the browser does not know what to do with raw object. In short, JSX can interpolate if the data is of primitive types like Integers or string. OBJECT just does not work. `<p>{aNumber}</p>` works, but not `<p>{{field1: "this is", field2: "an object"}}</p>`